# Typescript - Including declarations in prod build

Tags: typescript

It sounds like including .d.ts files in the production build is the way to go (vs creating a separate @types/my-lib package).

For example

```
dist/
  index.js
  index.d.ts
```

Adding to the prod payload feels irresponsible but it makes development easier so ok.

However, I'm in a situation where that library is using the type from another library that uses a separate @types/lib package. In my situation I'm using nodemailer, so for example:

```
// my-lib
import { someFunc } from "nodemailer"
type FooType = ReturnType< typeof someFunc >
```

That means I have to move @types/nodemailer from "devDependencies" to "dependencies" otherwise I'm forced to install "@types/nodemailer"  when developing from a new library that uses nodemailer.

Am I missing something? Adding nodemailer's entire @type pkg in prod feels excessive.

Comment: What are you building? Are you building a library or are you building a frontend/backend application?

Comment: Hi @vighnesh153 for this example it's one of the logging modules for an api for a web app

Comment: If avoiding the bandwidth costs of downloading type declarations is important to your production deployment process, then installing entire npm packages is wasteful to begin with: you could be tree-shaking all dead code during a bundle step and publishing/deploying only the optimized runtime bundle to maximize bandwidth efficiency.

Comment: hi @jsejcksn good point. It felt like I might be doing something wrong and there was a better way to install packages, but it sounds like the current process is fine. Thanks for the feedback.